# IntelliJ Idea 2016.2.4 cannot resolve symbol spark_2.11

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I made a following dependency in `build.sbt` file for apache-spark 2.11.

```
name := "Project1"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.8",
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.11.8",
"org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-parser-combinators_2.11" % "1.0.4",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.4"
)
```

However Intellij could not resolve `spark-core_2.11` dependency . I tried  multiple times  but could not succeed.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and is working fine for me !

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and is working fine for me ! But if its not working for you. Try to compile it from outside first and then try to re-import the project in your intellij . That might solve your problem !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in IntelliJ 2016.3.2 with almost the same Scala/Spark versions:

```
name := "some-project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

To get it to work I had to manually add the spark-core jar to my project libraries, ie:

- Right click on the project -> Open Module Settings
- Under Project Settings -> Libraries click + and select the 'Java' option.
- Browse for the jar. I found it in my Ivy cache - I assume it got there because I had run the 'update' task from the sbt console previously.

Comment: `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"  % "provided"` should do it. Don't forget to mark the core library as provided (not necessary to include, since the cluster will provide this library to your programm)